# Open/Save dialogs can't access directories outside home (Dolphin or snap)

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, directory, dolphin

When I open or save files in: Chromium, Signal, Doplhin, and few others, I can't load / save files in other folders.

It's not due to file permissions: Firefox, bash, double commander, kate - all have access without any questions asked, and without being root.

1. Can I allow these dialogs an unrestricted access (limited only by file permissions)
2. Can I instruct these programs to use another open/save dialog (like firefox does) ?

Edit:

I realize some of the symptoms might be due to snap sandboxing of some apps. This is annoying --> I need access to my own machine. It shouldn't be different than apt. I'm can reinstall  some apps as deb/ppa, but the problem still remains, and Dolphin: it isn't snap.